# Can't use == in LINQ Extension Method

Tags: linq

I've got the following struct that is the key for my dictionary:

```
public struct CodeAttribute
{
   public int ProcessorId;
   public Enums.TransactionType transactionType;
   public string ErrorMessage; 
}
```

I've got the following dictionary (one value for now as it's just an example):

```
var errors = new Dictionary<CodeAttribute, int>
{
   {CreateCodeAttributeList(2, Enums.TransactionType.Order, "Invalid ProcessorId sent in the Payment Request"), 100 }
};
```

And I'm trying to pull out the item in the dictionary that matches on the struct that has a match for both its ProcessorId and TransactionType properties:

```
private static string GetRelatedMessage(int errorCode, Dictionary<CodeAttribute, int> errorsList)
{
   CodeAttribute codeAttribute = errorsList.Where(e => e.Key.ProcessorId == _processorId)
                                           .Where(e => e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType) == errorCode;
   return codeAttribute.ErrorMessage;
}
```

I also want to match on error code as part of the filtering, not just paymentprocessorId and transactionType, just a side note.  The item in the dictionary must match all 3 values in order to get the right one in our case.

UPDATE

I tried this as well,and yes I get the error that it can't convert IEnumerable to CodeAtribute

```
CodeAttribute codeAttributes = errorsList.Where(e => e.Key.ProcessorId == _processorId)
                                         .Where(e => e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType)
                                         .Where(e => e.Value.Equals(errorCode));
```

UPDATE

with the help of Sam I think this may work

```
CodeAttribute codeAttribute = errorsList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.ProcessorId ==
_processorId && e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType
             && e.Value == errorCode).Key;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `where` clause returns `IEnumerable` not single value

Comment: What is `Where(e => e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType) == errorCode` supposed to mean?

Comment: Error I get is that it doesn't like the == operator, says it can't apply it in this case with the way I've tried to do it here

Comment: good catch SLacks, I'm trying also match on error code in addition to just the processorId and transactionType to pull the right item out of the dictionary

Comment: We need a better error message than that. _What_ doesn't it like about the == operator.

Comment: you try to compare `int` end `collection`

Comment: yea I just don't know how to do this then Grundy.  I thought that it would find a unique Single value in the dictionary if I match on the first two Wheres.

Comment: Using `.Key` at the end of the linq statement will work, but you will get a NullReferenceException if no items match your search criteria. Otherwise you can do a null check to catch this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you want

```
var codeAttribute = errorsList.FirstOrDefault(e => 
                                                e.Key.ProcessorId == _processorId
                                             && e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType
                                             && e.Value == errorCode);

    if(codeAttribute == null)
    {
      //no item matches in the dictionary.
    }

return codeAttribute.Key.ErrorMessage;
```

Note that `codeAttribute` will be a `KeyValuePair` so you will need the `codeAttribute.Key.ErrorMessage` as your return value.

You don't need to use `Where` as that will return an `IEnumerable` so this won't work if you want a single item.

---

Comment: Yes.. First or default will take a function that returns a boolean. (you could also use && in `Where` if you wanted an IEnumerable returning), you don't need to use two separate Where's

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to go with something like this:

```
CodeAttribute codeAttribute = errorsList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.ProcessorId == _processorId && e.Key.transactionType ==_transactionType)
```

Comment: This won't work as you will return back a `KeyValuePair` not `CodeAttribute`

Comment: right, i didn't notice that, he should go with var result = blah; and then take the key and value from that and create the object that he wants.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct, *I* would probably write it like this:

```
var errorMessage = errorsList
       .Where(e => e.Key.ProcessorId == _processorId
                   && e.Key.transactionType == _transactionType
                   && e.Value == errorCode)
       .Select(e => e.Key.ErrorMessage)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

That is, push the condition to filter earlier on, select the data I want from that result-set, and then take the first result (should one exist) of the transformed data.

Since the IEnumerable queries are *lazy* then this will still stop on the first sucessfully filtered object.

---

Since the source is a *Dictionary*, it may be also prudent to set up a relevant Equals/GetHashCode and structure the code such that it will be used.